# Print second Saturday of current month?

Tags: php-7.3

I want to print the second Saturday of current month.

My code is:

```
$now=date('d-m-Y');
$secondsat=date('d-m-Y',strtotime('second saturday of M Y'));
echo $now."<br/>", $secondsat."<br/>";
```

Output is:

```
13-02-2019
08-02-2019
```

means it print second Friday. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("second Saturday of ".date('M')." ".date('Y').""));
```

Try this one.

Comment: yes but at this time i replaced M to n. and It is working